# Typo3 9, MM-Relation loses translation if selected multiple

Tags: typo3, translation, extbase, relation, typo3-9.x

I created an extension with different MM-Relations. In example Products and Accessories. All accessories can be selected to every product. The problem is, if i select one accessory to one product the translation to another language works well. If i select one accessory to multiple products, the translation always uses the default language and no translation is shown. Could anyone please help me find a solution? 
Im using Typo3 9.5

Many thanks.

```php
public function findByUid($uid) {
    $uidArray = explode(",", $uid);
    $query = $this->createQuery();

    $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectSysLanguage(true);
    foreach ($uidArray as $key => $value) {
      $constraints[] = $query->equals('sys_language_uid', $value);
        $constraints[] = $query->equals('uid', $value);
      $constraints[] = $query->equals('l10n_parent', $value);
    }
    $query->matching(
        $query->logicalAnd(
            $query->logicalOr(
                $constraints
            ),
            $query->equals('hidden', 0),
            $query->equals('deleted', 0)
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some more information, since it does not help that much to see just the findByUid method. TCA and other configurations that define the MM relation might be useful here.

Comment: Hello and many thanks for your response. In the meantime I found my issue. It was a sorting Problem at my Model. I dont know why, but this was the solution for my Problem.